# Is it possible to authenticate from an external source while keeping authorization data local?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm currently working to develop a companion web application to a main web app. The main web app has a regular ASP.Net identity provider, which I have full access to and can create endpoints against.

I want to use just the username/password combo from the main application to Authenticate my users. The new secondary app will have provisions to authorize and maintain the users once they've been authenticated.

I imagine a sencario where a person enters the creds into the secondary app and it's sent to the primary endpoint. Primary then responds with a CanLogin and IsAuthorized flags. The secondary app then lets the person in and they can from there request further authorization to the system to be approved first by admins.

I've read over and over the ASP.Net Core documentation and I think something claims based is what I want. I just don't know at what point in the middleware I catch the authenticating method in order to check the primary?